# Asking question about competitive programming on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where can I ask a question about a competitive programming. I can not solve this problem and I need some help on how to solve the problem. The problem is from Codewars.com. is it possible to ask a question on helping solve a competitive programming question on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best option is a dedicated Stack Exchange site for competitive programming questions. If you agree, please support the proposal for such a site on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/104641/algorithmic-competitive-programming?referrer=wQLBXjIiUnECLWqm2IPhxQ2).

In theory, Stack Overflow can be used to get answers about competitive programming problems. But in practice, there's a higher bar to clear for CP questions than for other programming questions, due to cultural bias against CP on Stack Overflow. For example, see the comments on [Where to ask competitive programming related problems actually?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298212/where-to-ask-competitive-programming-related-problems-actually). The result is that people who want to ask Stack Overflow questions about CP problems have to formulate their questions to exclude any mention of competitive programming. Instead of making people do that, we should just have a separate community that can figure out its own rules about what CP questions are on-topic, without having to fight anti-CP sentiment (justified or not).

You can also use the [Quora Competitive Programming topic](https://www.quora.com/topic/Competitive-Programming), but Quora has issues with content quality.

Other references:

- [Stack Overflow vs. Competitive Programming Questions](http://www.redgreencode.com/stack-overflow-vs-competitive-programming-questions/)
- [Do We Need a Stack Exchange Site for Competitive Programmers?](http://www.redgreencode.com/need-stack-exchange-site-competitive-programmers/)
- [Can and should we include the Competitive Programming?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/676/can-and-should-we-include-the-competitive-programming) (on Programming Puzzles & Code Golf meta)
- [Can I ask competitive programming questions?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1147/can-i-ask-competitive-programming-questions) (on Computer Science meta)

Comment: I am going now to vote thank you very much

Comment: Note that users that disagree with this answer can equally access the linked Area 51 proposal and *formally* lodge their disagreement.

Comment: @Gnemlock There's no way to vote against Area 51 proposals. The only options are follow or ignore. However, I added a question, [Do we need another competitive programming site?](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/26021/do-we-need-another-competitive-programming-site), that people can write answers to. Or they can add another discussion topic. I'm actually interested in why people would be against the proposal. One reason is that a new site could take users away from the Programming Puzzles & Code Golf site. Maybe there are others.

Comment: Users can, in fact, choose to downvote the "Do we need another competetive programming site" question, or alternativley, upvote the answer that states "no".

Comment: @Gnemlock Downvoting the question means you think the question "doesn't show any research effort, is unclear, or is not useful," not that you disagree with the proposal. I think upvoting the "no" answer is the better option, assuming you think that competitive programming questions belong on the Code Golf site. If you have a different reason for being against the proposal, adding your own answer would be more helpful.

Comment: Why so many downvotes?

Comment: @pushpen.paul People who disagree that there should be a separate CP site on the SE network.

Answer (score 6):

It depends entirely on the nature of the competition. You may direct questions relating to a problem in programming to Stack Overflow, but there are further considerations:

- Questions deemed to be "too broad" will be closed. This is judged on a case by case basis, so if you are not sure, ask at the Stack Overflow meta.
- Any solution taken from a Stack Exchange site must credit both the *site* and the *user who posted the answer*. If the competitive nature of your task prevents you from doing so, you should not ask your question through Stack Exchange. Potential answers would not be viable,  as you would not be allowed to use them without appropriate credit. This is not as applicable to Codewars, as far as I know, as you are not *publishing* code; you are simply completing exercises.
- In regards to a codewars.com exercise, you should tread lightly. While you *can* ask the question, it *may not* be received well. Once again, you should direct yourself to the Stack Overflow meta. Ask about *how* you should ask such a question; if you shouldn't, you will still get an answer. You will also get advice to ensure that if you *do* ask, the question has a better reception.
- Consider trying to figure out the problem, and asking for *clarification*. Either way, show research effort, or expect a bad reception.

Comment: When asked on Stack Overflow the [Question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) might be handy, on top of the Help Center.

Comment: I was under the impression that content posted in SO is under  cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required. Which requires crediting the author but does not require crediting the publishing house.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos, to be honest, you may be right. When it comes up, here on meta, I have only ever seen it quoted as 'credit SE and credit the user'.